# Getting error while creating node in postgres-xc cluster database

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xc

I have tried to create postgres-xc cluster database.So i followed their documentation do that (http://postgres-xc.sourceforge.net/docs/1_1/install-short.html)

After following that documentation procedure I'm not able to create node. I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "NODE"

when running following command

```
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql -c "CREATE NODE datanode1 WITH (TYPE = 'datanode', PORT = 15432)" postgres
```

Can anyone help me to do solve this.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a "normal" Postgres installation to which `psql` is connecting to?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i didnt get your question

Answer (score 1):

I suspect a_horse_with_no_name is right.  postgres-xc and postgresql are different codebases and you can't run `CREATE NODE` on PostgreSQL and have it work.  You must be running Postgres-XC.

To find out, run `SELECT version()` from psql.

To install Postgres-XC the first step is to actually install the Postgres-XC software either from packages or from source (by compiling).